# Proving Geometric Inequality Using Equation Discriminant

Tags: inequalities, analytic-geometry, discriminant

I met this question before:

> An acute $\triangle ABC$ (you can imagine $BC$ below) has a point $D$ on side $AC$. The line parallel to BC through $D$ meets $AB$ at $E$, and the parallel line $BD$ through $E$ meets $AC$ at $F$. Try to prove that $AB\geq 4DF$.

You can find the answer by establishing a planar Cartesian coordinate system and using the proportional relationship between similar triangle segments. But this approach has some complications.

The answer gives a really clever solution:

1. get the quadratic equation $AD^2-AB\cdot AD+AB\cdot DF=0$ through $\frac{DF}{DB}=\frac{DE}{BC}=\frac{AD}{AB}$ (*proved using similar triangles*) and $DB=AB-AD$.
2. draw the conclusion based on $\Delta \geq 0$.

Today, I encountered a similar problem:

> as shown in the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giH3h.jpg), point F no longer exists, but the angle between BD and C is equal to $\angle A$. Prove that $BD+DE-BE\leq \frac 1 4 C_{\triangle ABC}$.

There are many similarities between the two questions. For example, there are many sets of similar triangles in the figure, and all that needs to be proved is an inequality (*What's even more ingenious is that they both need to compare the magnitude of 4 times one number with the other number!*). I think this problem should also have a solution similar to the previous one.

I'm curious if there is a solution similar to the first question. And, how can I be keen to discover this interesting solution.

Comment: What are "the angle between BD and C" and even more mysterious $C_{\triangle ABC}$?